# Where is firefox binaries on alipne docker image?

Tags: java, docker, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a docker file as shown below

```
FROM gradle:5.2.1-jdk-alpine AS build
USER root
RUN apk update
RUN apk add firefox-esr
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/firefox:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/usr/lib/firefox:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:${PATH}"
```

I am trying to run selenium firefox web driver.

```
            File pathToBinary = new File("/usr/lib/firefox/firefox");
            FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
            DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.setHeadless(true);
            desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options.setBinary(firefoxBinary));
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

It keeps throwing me

```
Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Comment: The file location for Firefox looks correct. Could it be an error/bug in Selenium on Alpine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Community Repository first:

- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Community_Repository

then do:

```
apk update
apk add firefox-esr
```

Answer (score 0):

use path as : /usr/bin/firefox

File pathToBinary = new File("/usr/bin");